# Why is MudBlazor SelectList with FluentValidation throwing "Error in validation func"

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I´m using Blazor Server and have FluentValidation on my model which looks like this:

```
    public class ItemModel
    {
        public ItemModel()
        {
            Items = new string[]{"A","B","C"};
        }
        public string[] Items {get;set;}
        public string Item {get;set;} = string.Empty;
    }

    public class ValidateItemModel : AbstractValidator<ItemModel>
    {
        public ValidateItemModel()
        {
            RuleFor(_ => _.Item).NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("You need to select an item");
        }

        public Func<object, string, IEnumerable<string>> Validate => (model, propertyName) =>
        {
            var result = Validate(ValidationContext<T>.CreateWithOptions((T)model, 
            x => x.IncludeProperties(propertyName)));

            if (result.IsValid)
                return Array.Empty<string>();
            return result.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
        };
    }
```

And in DI I´m registering my validator like so:

```
services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<ValidateItemModel>();
```

In my MudBlazor component I´m defining a MudSelect like so:

```
@inject ValidateItemModel validator

<MudItem xs="12" md="4">
    <MudSelect T="string" @bind-Value="@Model.Item" Validation="validator.Validate">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
        {
            <MudSelectItem T="string" Value="@Model.Item">@item</MudSelectItem>
        }
    </MudSelect>
</MudItem>
```

However, when I´m validating the form on post, or changing the value of the select, this error message comes up:
[image]

Validation works on other elements such as MudText, but **values from MudSelect doesn´t even enter the validation Func**. The documentation shows no examples that promotes a diverging approach from regular inputs when it comes to selectlists.

Anyone with a similar experience with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing

```
    For="@(()=> Model.Item)
```

on my MudSelect.

Adding this solved it. This question should probably be archived as typo or "RTFM".